# Why this one always return Memory Access Violation?

Tags: tensorflow

`vector output_array(1);
output_array[0] = 0;

```
            std::unique_ptr<float[]>  tensor_data2 (new float[1]);
            memcpy(tensor_data2.get(), output_array.data(), sizeof(float) * 1);

            int64_t shape2[] = { 1 };
            TF_Tensor* output_tensor = TF_NewTensor(TF_FLOAT, shape2, 1, tensor_data2.get(), sizeof(float) * 1, {}, nullptr);
```

`
I want to make output_tensor without error.